# Disadvantage of using NSMutableArray vs NSArray?

Tags: iphone, cocoa, cocoa-touch, nsmutablearray, nsarray

I'm using an array to store cached objects loaded from a database in my iPhone app, and was wondering: are there any significant disadvantages to using NSMutableArray that I should know of?

edit: I know that NSMutableArray can be modified, but I'm looking for specific reasons (performance, etc..) why one would use NSArray instead. I assume there would be a performance difference, but I have no idea whether it's significant or not.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

If you're loading objects from a database and you know *exactly* how many objects you have, you would likely get the best performance from `NSMutableArray`s `arrayWithCapacity:` method, and adding objects to it until full, so it allocates all the memory at once if it can.

<s>Behind the scenes, they're secretly the same thing - `NSArray` and `NSMutableArray` are both implemented with `CFArray`s via toll free bridging (a `CFMutableArrayRef` and a `CFArrayRef` are typedef's of the same thing, `__CFArray *`)</s> *

`NSArray` and `NSMutableArray` should have the same performance/complexity (access time being O(lg N) at worst and O(1) at best) and the only difference being how much memory the two objects would use - `NSArray` has a fixed limit, while `NSMutableArray` can use up as much space as you have free.

The comments in [CFArray.h](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/CF/CF-550/CFArray.h) have much more detail about this.

*: As Catfish_Man points out below, this isn't true anymore.

Comment: Note that NSArray is no longer implemented in terms of CFArray (though it was four years ago when this answer was written)

Comment: Where have you read about performance of data structure in objective C?

Comment: @George The performance of data structures in Objective-C is pretty much the same as it is in other languages. If you want Foundation-specific details, http://ridiculousfish.com/blog/posts/array.html has some insights, although things specific details have changed in the past decade.

Answer (score 25):

The performance difference of using NSArray versus NSMutable array arises primarily when you use an API that wants to copy the array.  if you send -copy to an immutable array, it just bumps the retain count, but sending -copy to a mutable array will allocate heap memory.

Comment: Bumping the retain count is much faster.

Answer (score 14):

In addition, NSMutableArray is not threadsafe, while NSArray is (same with all the mutable vs. "immutable" objects). This could be a huge problem if you're multithreading.

Answer (score 9):

The main disadvantage to `NSMutableArray` is that an object owning a `NSMutableArray` may have the array changed behind its back if another object also owns it. This may require you to code your object more defensively, less aggressively chasing performance.

If the `NSMutableArray` is not exposed outside of the object, this isn't a concern.

`NSArray` is a better choice for sharing, precisely because it is immutable. Every object using it can assume it won't change, and doesn't need to defensively make a copy of it.

This is **probably** the same reason that `NSDictionary` copies its keys, rather than simply retaining them: it needs to be sure that they won't mutate, and copying is the only way to guarantee that.

Answer (score 2):

You can't modify `NSArray` once it is created. If you need to add/remove objects from your array then you will use `NSMutableArray` - not much options for that. I assume `NSArray` is optimized for fixed array operations. Mutable array provides flexibly of being modifiable.