# Objective C NSArray Vs NSMutableArray performance

Tags: objective-c, arrays, nsmutablearray, nsarray

With `NSMutableArray` we get additional methods like

- `addObject`
- `insertObject`
- `removeObjectAtIndex`

Why we want to use non-mutable `NSArray` when we get additional methods in `NSMutableArray`? Is there any performance penalty when using `NSMutableArray` over `NSArray`?

Comment: Memory is quite a good reason. Block any attempts of modification is a good one too.

Comment: Why would you use a mutable array for things like storing the letters of the alphabet? Or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

Just check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1746204/disadvantage-of-using-nsmutablearray-vs-nsarray):

**It is mentioned in the above link, just portraying in my words:**

> While calling an  API that wants to copy the array and if you
>   send -copy to an immutable array(NSArray), it just bumps the retain
>   count, but while sending -copy to a mutable array(NSMutableArray) will
>   allocate heap memory. So bumping the retain count is much faster than
>   allocating heap memory.
>
> Here comes the performance issue.